# BigQuery Row-Level Expiration

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to set an expiration time on the individual rows of a table in BigQuery?

I don't want the entire table to expire, but I would like to be able to set an expiration date on rows. For example, if the expiration date was 31 days, I would like any row that was inserted more than 31 days ago to be removed from the table.

Answer (score 4):

There is no expiration on row level (at least as of now)!
What you can do to accomplish very similar (by result) is to use relatively recently introduced [Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables)
Each partition can have its own expiration - so you can set your table in such a way that all rows belonging to particular day will expire when you need them to

Answer (score 3):

If your table is a [partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables), you can set an expiration time on the partitions within the table using the [`timePartitioning.expirationMs`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#timePartitioning.expirationMs) field.  This could automatically expire a partition after 31 days, for example.

Comment: Can the expiration time for partitions be updated dynamically? If I use a patch call from the API to change the timePartitioning.expirationMs field, will all partitions that have been around longer than the expiration time be removed? If I updated the timePartitioning.expirationMs of a table that already existed to 31 days, would any partition older than 31 days be removed? Would a partition that was already created expire 31 days after it was originally created?

Comment: Each partition has its creation time stored in meta-table (`SELECT * FROM [yourtable$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]`), so I would expect it will handle expiration the way you described. but that's a guess only - i haven't had chance to test it. Hope Danny will update us on this

Comment: Yes, in your example - a partition containing old data would expire 31 days after the creation time of the data (this is not the partition's date, but it is the time at which data was added to that partition).